# Assigning multiple topics to each text when topic modelling

Tags: r, nlp, lda, topic-modeling, quanteda

Using the quanteda functions below, I want to assign multiple topics to each text, but am uncertain as to how to achieve this. At the moment it is only assigning a single topic to each text.

```
corp_news <- data_corpus_inaugural

news_dfm <- dfm(corp_news, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbol = TRUE, remove=stopwords("en"))

tmod_lda <- textmodel_lda(news_dfm, k = 10)

news_dfm$topic <- topics(tmod_lda)
```

Comment: Hi - There is no function `textmodel_lda()`. This sounds more like a question for a topic modelling package.

Answer (score 0):

This is not implemented in the `seededlda` package you are using, and I don't think any of the other LDA packages does this either. However, `topics` simply selects the topic with the highest theta value. This is straight from the [source code](https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda/blob/b1c662d28e82fe28bf844979935d09b245d46737/R/seededlda.R#L128-L135):

```r
#' @export
#' @method topics textmodel_lda
topics.textmodel_lda <- function(x) {
    result <- factor(max.col(x$theta), labels = colnames(x$theta),
                     levels = seq_len(ncol(x$theta)))
    result[rowSums(x$data) == 0] <- NA
    return(result)
}
```

We can modify this function to return an arbitrary number of topics orderd from most to least likely:

```r
topicsn <- function(x, n = 1) {
  if (n == 1) {
    result <- factor(max.col(x$theta), labels = colnames(x$theta),
                     levels = seq_len(ncol(x$theta)))
  } else if (n > 1) {
    result <- factor(apply(x$theta, 1, order)[, seq_len(n)],
                     labels = colnames(x$theta),
                     levels = seq_len(ncol(x$theta)))
    result <- matrix(result, ncol = n)
    colnames(result) <- paste0("top_topic_", seq_len(n))
  }
  
  return(result)
}
```

Now I'm running your code again (slightly changed since the syntax is different in the new quanteda:

```r
library(quanteda)
library(seededlda)
corp_news <- data_corpus_inaugural

news_dfm <- corp_news %>% 
  tokens(remove_numbers = TRUE, 
         remove_symbol = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
  dfm()

tmod_lda <- textmodel_lda(news_dfm, k = 10)
```

And now we can use the function to return two top topics:

```r
topicsn(tmod_lda, 2)
#>       top_topic_1 top_topic_2
#>  [1,] "topic3"    "topic1"   
#>  [2,] "topic10"   "topic2"   
#>  [3,] "topic4"    "topic4"   
#>  [4,] "topic1"    "topic5"   
#>  [5,] "topic5"    "topic9"   
#>  [6,] "topic9"    "topic10"  
#>  [7,] "topic8"    "topic3"   
#>  [8,] "topic2"    "topic8"   
#>  [9,] "topic6"    "topic6"   
#> [10,] "topic7"    "topic7"
```

For the first text, the most prevalent topic is "topic3" followed by "topic1" and so on.